# "Missing method body" error while declaring a constructor in java

Tags: java

I don't know why, but when i'm trying to overload a constructor, Netbeans shows an error "Missing method body or declare Abstract".. here's the class-->

```
   public class Car extends Vehicle{

    public String mfname;
    public void setmfname(String b){
   this.mfname=b;
    }
   public Car(String name,int weight,int year,String mfname){
   super (name,weight,year);
   this.mfname=mfname;
    }
   public Car();  // this line has the error 
    }
```

Comment: As the error said, you have to implement  that constructor or declare it with abstract keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to have a parameterless constructor, add a body to it :

```
public Car()
{
    ...
}
```

If not, just remove the `public Car();` line.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors cannot be abstracted, even in abstract classes.

The error message is slightly ambiguous, as it "interprets" your `Car()` constructor as a non-implemented method.

You will need to provide an implementation to this constructor, even an empty one.

You can also invoke `super()` as the first line in your `Car()` implementation to invoke the `Vehicle`'s empty constructor if provided, or the `Vehicle`'s default constructor if no parametrized constructor is declared in `Vehicle`.

**Examples** (assuming `Vehicle` has no declared constructor, or a parameter-less one)

```
public Car() {
    super();
}
```

... or ...

```
public Car() {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but removing 'Public'  keyword and adding an empty body worked for me !